# why I can't connect to the tweet API account?

Tags: python, tweepy

there is an error of my coding to connect with the tweet API, how can I debug it?

```
#create the authentication object
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret,callback_uri)
auth.sec_access_token(accessToken,accessTokenSercet)
AttributeError: 'OAuthHandler' object has no attribute 'sec_access_token'
```

Comment: There's nowhere else on the internet at all that says that `sec_access_token` is in tweepy. From the documentation, all I can see is `set_access_token`. Surely that's what you meant?

Comment: You have misspelled "set". Also, I hypothesize that you are a Dvorak typist, where "t" and "c" are right next to each other.

Comment: I have voted to close this question for the reason of "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Comment: thank you so much, eventually I tackle the problem as I misspelled "set"